# Correct location (in Gradle) to put code that should be run in _all_ test cases?

Tags: groovy, junit, gradle

Just wondering... I have some code (disabling certain logging output) that I'd like to be run before *all* tests...

I do not see any such examples for JUnit/Groovy testing in the samples directory... is there a good/correct place to put such code?

Thank you!

Misha

p.s. I am using the 0.9 preview 3 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Test](http://gradle.org/0.9-preview-3/docs/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html) source code, you should be able to set a beforeSuite/beforeTest Closure on the test Task. I haven't tried it, but I imagine it works something like this:

```
test {
    beforeSuite{
        //run custom setup code here
    }
}
```